# Doubled up RAM to 32 GB - now how to speed up a "LAPP" server?

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, performance-tuning, rhel6

I run a small [Facebook game](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/video-preferans) at a CentOS 6.3 quad core machine with PostgreSQL 8.4.3 + few PHP scripts (doing mostly `select` queries) + 1 Perl daemon and even though the server worked ok, I've suggested my users to double up the RAM to 32 GB and they have collected money for that.

Now my problem is that I don't know, which knob to turn and how to really use the additional memory to speed up the server.

Below is my top output at the peak time (evenings) - as you see, 27 GB of RAM aren't used:

```
# top - 18:47:55 up 23:12,  2 users,  load average: 2.17, 2.31, 2.56
Tasks: 246 total,   2 running, 244 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 12.1%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 87.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32790380k total,  5296664k used, 27493716k free,   197132k buffers
Swap:  2096056k total,        0k used,  2096056k free,  3815840k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
12363 postgres  20   0 4376m 717m 710m S 40.6  2.2   2:03.48 postmaster
 3842 nobody    20   0  118m  23m 3920 S 12.0  0.1  46:24.68 pref.pl
 9178 postgres  20   0 4375m 518m 514m S 11.3  1.6  53:50.63 postmaster
12380 postgres  20   0 4377m 668m 660m S 11.3  2.1   2:33.26 postmaster
12243 postgres  20   0 4377m 668m 662m S  9.3  2.1   2:20.49 postmaster
12438 postgres  20   0 4374m 502m 498m S  6.3  1.6   1:03.34 postmaster
12249 postgres  20   0 4384m 852m 839m S  3.0  2.7   3:59.11 postmaster
12241 postgres  20   0 4378m 632m 625m S  1.7  2.0   2:48.62 postmaster
12156 apache    20   0  366m  27m  17m S  1.0  0.1   0:05.12 httpd
   36 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:01.32 events/1
  100 root      39  19     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:06.04 khugepaged
 9217 postgres  20   0 21976 1036  516 S  0.3  0.0   1:01.07 pgbouncer
12010 apache    20   0  376m  37m  17m S  0.3  0.1   0:07.58 httpd
12280 apache    20   0  370m  30m  16m S  0.3  0.1   0:03.17 httpd
12362 apache    20   0  365m  15m 6816 R  0.3  0.0   0:01.90 httpd
12457 apache    20   0  360m 9.8m 3456 S  0.3  0.0   0:00.14 httpd
    1 root      20   0 19352 1584 1284 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.03 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd

# vmstat 10
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 6  2      0 27323416 196988 3852536    0    0     3   165   15    9 14  0 84  2  0
 1  0      0 27422148 197012 3814860    0    0     0  5284 4784 2104 46  1 51  2  0
 1  0      0 27454748 197020 3826656    0    0     4  1734 2021 1200 16  0 83  1  0
 0  2      0 27514008 197028 3813464    0    0     0   702 1475 1208  8  0 90  2  0
 0  0      0 27465612 197040 3813968    0    0     0  1435 1764 1725 10  0 85  5  0
 1  0      0 27459260 197060 3814248    0    0     0  2032 2667 1304 22  0 76  1  0
 1  0      0 27440076 197064 3827064    0    0     0  1604 3146 2109 27  0 72  1  0
 1  0      0 27466796 197068 3814868    0    0     2  1241 2014 1637 13  0 83  3  0
 4  0      0 27380104 197072 3848256    0    0     0  1064 2375  894 20  0 79  1  0
 1  0      0 27488168 197096 3815296    0    0     0  2075 2697 2220 23  0 75  1  0
 1  0      0 27462168 197116 3821380    0    0     0   871 1750  943 13  0 86  1  0
 4  0      0 27432100 197128 3822320    0    0     0  3980 4767 2340 46  1 53  1  0
 0  0      0 27493716 197132 3815844    0    0     0  1871 3209 2078 27  0 72  1  0
 3  0      0 27424284 197132 3827036    0    0     0  1452 2551 1487 18  0 78  3  0
 3  0      0 27435428 197160 3824116    0    0     0  2066 3430 2082 29  0 70  1  0
 2  0      0 27452004 197172 3817440    0    0     0  1356 2722 1895 23  0 76  1  0
 2  0      0 27436668 197176 3826648    0    0     0  1633 3629 2162 30  0 69  1  0
 1  0      0 27439924 197204 3823124    0    0     0  1502 1786 1293 14  0 86  0  0
 0  0      0 27466696 197212 3816780    0    0     0  1200 1701 1164 13  0 86  0  0
 3  0      0 27432204 197212 3818344    0    0     0  2587 2098 2154 16  0 83  1  0
 2  0      0 27421088 197224 3827224    0    0     0  1229 2635 1421 21  0 75  3  0
 3  0      0 27319136 197232 3832088    0    0    13  2965 4220 1951 40  0 59  1  0

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
```

What I've already done:

/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf (local connections only)

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 4096MB
work_mem = 16M
```

/etc/php.ini

```
memory_limit = 300M
[PostgresSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = Off    # because I use pgbouncer
```

/etc/pgbouncer.ini (local connections only too)

```
max_client_conn = 600
default_pool_size = 80
```

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (didn't modify yet):

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers      10
MinSpareServers    8
MaxSpareServers   30
ServerLimit      512
MaxClients       512
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions please on how to speed up my Linux Apache PostgreSQL PHP (aka "LAPP") server?

I was actually hoping that Linux would use the additional memory for caching disks, but this doesn't seem to happen?

**UPDATE:**

I've installed `iotop` and it show PostreSQL doing SELECT's and my Perl daemon (for the Facebook game):

```
Total DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE: 101.72 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
20555 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s   78.25 K/s  0.00 %  0.28 % postgres: pref pref [local] SELECT
26397 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s 1674.51 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % postgres: pref pref [local] SELECT
26392 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    3.91 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd
26402 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s    3.22 M/s  0.00 %  0.00 % postgres: pref pref [local] SELECT
26448 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s   62.60 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd
26486 be/4 postgres    0.00 B/s    7.82 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % postgres: pref pref [local] SELECT
26524 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    3.91 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd
15392 be/4 nobody      0.00 B/s    3.91 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % perl -w /usr/local/pref/pref.pl
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
    4 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
    5 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
    6 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/0]
    7 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/1]
    8 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/1]
    9 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/1]
```

It seems that disk caching works ok, since the `read` is always 0 ?

Comment: Regarding caching: how much data do you have that would need it? If your codebase and database are actually quite small, there won't be a lot of data to cache in the first place.

Comment: That's true - I don't have much (only 8 GB of user avatars + the PHP scripts)

Comment: Size doesn't matter. You knew it before. Time to start profiling your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching is done on more of a demand basis. Say whenever you do a read() operation on a file, the file is cached. So, if your database size and program size is low, then it would cache as much as it need to. Upon demand, when more queries will be done, it will be cached automatically.

You are not hitting any swapping which is awesome. There is a parameter vm.vfs_cache_pressure which determines how the cached memory will be reclaimed compared to reclamation of swap. But, you haven't reached the phase of memory usage where you should start to tweak the VM.

My 2 cents ;)

Comment: I think he has simply turned off swap by writing `0` to `/proc/sys/vm/swapiness`.

Comment: Setting `vm.swappiness` to 0 doesn't disable swap, it just keeps the system from swapping out inactive pages in the background until it's absolutely required to keep a memory allocation from failing.

Comment: Yep, kernel doc says vm.swappiness will dictate how aggressive kernel will be to swap. But, it does _not_ disable swapping.

Comment: No, I haven't turned off swap, but yes actually I had swap used before (with 16 GB) and now (with 32 GB) it seems not to be used, cool.